# Initial size of widgets inside a QSplitter

Tags: qt, qt4

I have a vertical QSplitter with two widgets inside whose layouts contains more widgets. How can I set the initial height of the second widget to its minimum possible height (wrap to its content)?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Possible, set vertical size policy of widget to Maximum.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `QSplitter::setSizes` to set widgets' sizes. You can obtain total available space using `QSplitter::size`. You can obtain minimal width of the second widget using `QWidget::sizeHint`. It will help you to calculate values that should be passed to `setSizes`.